# Is there any support to the Black Jews theory?

Tags: history

Is there anything to back up that the Jews were really black? Is there any sources that refute this? I see so many people claiming this.

Comment: Define "black". If you are talking about Avraham, then you need to look at the makeup of Charan and the surrounding area after the dispersion of the tower of Babel. After Sinai, there would have been a number (unknown) who joined the Jewish people as part of the Eirev Rav. There may also have been an unknown number who *converted* and joined the Bnai Yisrael during the slavery in Egypt. Given those possibilities, one cannot answer the question specifically. Many of the claims (from articles making the claim) define *black* as even one ancestor from Africa, no matter how far back.

Comment: Are you asking whether any blacks were Jews historically, or whether Yaakov's family was black, or something else?  Please [edit] to clarify.  I've put this question on hold in the meantime so people don't try to guess; after you edit it'll be reviewed for possible reopening.

Comment: There was Ebed-Melech the Cushite, an official in late Judean government, who helped out Jeremiah and was praised for it.  Doesn't specifically say he was Jewish, but he probably was as observant as the job required..and was a real nice guy, besides.

Comment: If you like an answer, consider marking it accepted.

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no historic evidence that the [Black Hebrews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Hebrew_Israelites), who seem to be referenced in the question, are Jewish. I am not aware of a single historian who takes this alternative version of Jewish history seriously See [this article](http://traditionarchive.org/news/originals/Volume%2015/No.%201/Black%20Jews.pdf) by [R. Dr. J. David Bleich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._David_Bleich) which discusses their history from their inception in the second half of the 19th century.

This is distinct from the issue of Ethiopian Jews, for example discussed in the article.